# Flash Wierdness - #2032 Error but Apache returns 200

Tags: actionscript-3

I have a small flash app that loads a small (10 line) xml file. All works well most of the time. However, sometimes I see the flash app fail to load the xml file and throw a #2032 error.

When the app fails to load the xml file, it re-requests it every 15 seconds. These re-requests all fail by throwing a 2032 error but, tailing the Apache logs shows http status 200 for each request.

The Flash ULRLoader receives a http status event 200, then immediately displays a #2032 error. Any thoughts about what may be happening here?

Thanks!

code:

```
    public class XMLLoader 
{
    private var xml:XML;
    private var loader:URLLoader = new URLLoader();
    private var callback:Function;


    function XMLLoader(c:Function = null)
    {
        callback = c;
    }

    public function loadData(url:String = null):void
    {
        loader.addEventListener(Event.COMPLETE, onLoaded);
        loader.addEventListener(IOErrorEvent.IO_ERROR, onIOError);

        loader.addEventListener(Event.OPEN, onOpen);
        loader.addEventListener(ProgressEvent.PROGRESS, onProgress);
        loader.addEventListener(SecurityErrorEvent.SECURITY_ERROR, onSecurityError);
        loader.addEventListener(HTTPStatusEvent.HTTP_STATUS, onHttpStatus);

        loader.load(new URLRequest(url + "?now=" + timeNow()));
    }

    private function timeNow()
    {
        var timeNow:Date = new Date();
        return timeNow.valueOf();
    }

    private function onOpen(event:Event):void
    {
        callback("Open: " +  String(event));
    }

    private function onProgress(event:ProgressEvent):void
    {
        callback("Progress: loaded:" + event.bytesLoaded + " total: "  + event.bytesTotal);
    }

    private function onSecurityError(event:SecurityErrorEvent):void
    {
        callback("Security Error: " + event);
    }

    private function onHttpStatus(event:HTTPStatusEvent):void
    {
        callback("Http Status: " +  event);
    }

    private function onLoaded(event:Event):void
    {
        xml = new XML(event.target.data);
        callback("ISLD: " +  event);

        callback("Success", xml);
    }

    private function onIOError(event:IOErrorEvent):void
    {
        callback("IOError" + event);
    }
```

Comment: Why in **public function loadData(url:String = null):void** url = null???? Open page in firefox or chrome and check network activity

Comment: Yeah, Ilya Z is right here. That parameter shouldn't be optional because the method depends on that parameter not being null.